# Getting syntax error in update query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I'm getting syntax error.

> Unclosed quatation mark after the chareter string 'OKWhere
>   UerName=Sam'. IncorrectSysntax near 'OKWhere UserName=sam'.

Code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE SystemInfo SET" + " UserName='" + UserName + "',
UserDomainName='" + UserDomainName + "',UserMachineName='" + UserMachineName 
+"',UserIP='" + UserIP + "', UserOsVersion='" + UserOsVersion + 
"',UserSystemDirectory='" + UserSystemDirectory + "',UserCurrentDirectory='" + 
UserCurrentDirectory + "', ProcessorName='" + ProcessorName + "', 
ProcessMnufacturer='" + ProcessMnufacturer + "',ProcessorID='" + ProcessorID + 
"',ProcessorDescription='" + ProcessorDescription + "',ProcessorVersion='" + 
ProcessorVersion + "',ProcessorStatus='" + ProcessorStatus + "',ProcessorDeviceId='" + 
ProcessorDeviceId + "', OSCaption='" + OSCaption + "',OSSerialNumber='" +  
SSerialNumber + "',OSManufacturer ='" + OSManufacturer + "',OSVersion='" + OSVersion + 
"', OSStatus='" + OSStatus + "',OSName='" + OSName + "', BiosName='" + BiosName + 
"',BiosVersion='" + BiosVersion + "',BiosSerialNumber='" + BiosSerialNumber + "', 
BiosManufacturer='" + BiosManufacturer + "',BiosCurrentlanguage='" + 
BiosCurrentlanguage + "', BiosStatus='" + BiosStatus + "Where UserName=" + 
UserName.ToString ();
```

Comment: Before proceeding any further, you might want to read about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: To expand on @Frédéric's point: if the above is how you are accustomed to writing SQL, you need to *stop right now*; that is ***really really*** dangerous. As in "I could take over your database server with nothing more than a web-browser" dangerous.

Comment: Too bad you get an error. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 6):

```
BiosStatus + "Where UserName="
```

You need a space before the `WHERE` clause and add quotations around `UserName`, it should look like:

```
BiosStatus + " Where UserName='" + UserName.ToString() + "'"
```

As an additional note try and use [paramerterized queries](http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/). This will prevent `SQL Injection` attacks.  You could achieve this by doing something like the following:

```
command.CommandText = "UPDATE TABLE " +  
         "SET BiosStatus = $BiosStatus, BiosManufacturer = $BiosManufacturer " +  
         "WHERE UserName = $UserName";  

 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$BiosStatus", BiosStatus);  
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$BioManufacturer", BiosManufacturer);  
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("$UserName", UserName);
```

Comment: It's also missing an apostrophe.

Comment: +1 for the parameterized query code example.  Though nobody seems to have noticed that the value for the WHERE clause is also missing single quotes (I'm assuming that UserName is a varchar/char column, of course).

Comment: @Tim/Grant - added the quotations

Comment: @Downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: glad to see an answer that doesn't promote concatenation!

Answer (score 1):

Parameters. Always always parameters. Actually, since all the inputs seem to be properties of the current instance (`this`), a tool like "dapper" could *really* help you out here:

```
conn.Execute(@"UPDATE SystemInfo SET
UserName=@UserName,
UserDomainName=@UserDomainName,
UserMachineName=@UserMachineName,
UserIP=@UserIP,
-- ...lots skipped...
BiosCurrentlanguage=@BiosCurrentlanguage,
BiosStatus=@BiosStatus
Where UserName=@UserName", this);
```

the `this` as the second parameter uses all the properties of the current instance *that are present in the SQL* to add the parameters, so it will add `@UserName`, `@UserDomainName`, etc...

You can of course do the same manually with raw ADO.NET - it is just a lot more work:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE SystemInfo SET
UserName=@UserName,
UserDomainName=@UserDomainName,
UserMachineName=@UserMachineName,
UserIP=@UserIP,
-- ...lots skipped...
BiosCurrentlanguage=@BiosCurrentlanguage,
BiosStatus=@BiosStatus
Where UserName=@UserName";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", ((object)UserName) ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserDomainName", ((object)UserDomainName) ?? DBNull.Value);
// ...lots skipped...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BiosCurrentlanguage", ((object)BiosCurrentlanguage) ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BiosStatus", ((object)BiosStatus) ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to correct

form

```
BiosStatus + "Where UserName="
```

to

```
BiosStatus + " Where UserName='"+  UserName.ToString ()+ "'";
```

Comment: This remains *really* dangerous code - helping the OP to *add* a huge security hole is not necessarily helping them

Comment: You absolutely right, the best way is to add parameters. But he initial question was not how to make code more secure.

Comment: yes, but presumably the user wants it to at least *work*; concatenation doesn't even offer that reliably; parameters aren't just about security: they are also about *correctness*.  Let's hope no BIOS manufacturers ever use an apostrophe or single-quote in their descriptions, eh? And that there are no users called "Mc'Dougal". Additionally, the code you posted simply won't compile - the `'` needs to be inside the C# string literal, and there is a semicolon that needs to be removed

Comment: You r right for the code and i have fixed. You r right for what you said, but the fisrt thought(which is apparently wrong coding) was to fix the problem and then post best practice.

Comment: :( You r right again. I am not corefull.